# How to control the output current in when using a transistor as a switch?

Tags: transistors, current, switches

Assuming that I have the following circuit where I use a transistor as a switch:

[image: Transistor as a switch]

When the transistor is not active Vout will be equal to the Vcc and the current will become very high right? So if I want to add a combinatorial circuit or any other IC what should I do about that?

**edit:**
The circuit that lead me to this question:

[image: my circuit]

S1 simulates what happens if the IR gate is blocked, and U1 is a quadruple NAND gate IC wired to form a NOT gate. I posted this question because XMM2 is measuring extremely high currents. Is that because the simulator is ignoring the saturation limit of the phototransistor?

Comment: In this circuit:
`When the transistor is not active Vout will be equal to the Vcc` -that is true.
`the current will become very high` -if you mean RLcurrent it is zero.
The things changes if you connect something to Vout.

Comment: @MichalPodmanický I'm talking about the case where I have something connected to the output.

Comment: If you connect Led between Vout and 0V in this state, the Led will be ON and current thru Led will be `I_led=(Vcc-3)/RL`. Considering Vcc=5V and RL=1k the Led current will be 2mA. The voltage on Vout will be 3V now due to Led IV curve.

Comment: The whole transistor can be negleted in this state because of its CE resistance more than 1Mohm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> When the transistor is not active Vout will be equal to the Vcc and the current will become very high right?

No, the current through the transistor and R<sub>L</sub>will be zero. (Look at your switch equivalent. Where could the current flow to?)

> So if I want to add a combinatorial circuit or any other IC what should I do about that?

Adding a second switch in parallel with the existing one will create OR logic. Switching on either one will power the load, R<sub>L</sub>. In the transistor circuit that means adding a second R<sub>in</sub> and transistor.

Comment: "the current through the transistor and RL will be zero" That's what I thought at first but I simulated it on Multisim and it gave me a crazy high current so I got a little puzzled. Do you know why is that so?

Comment: Then the simulator is wrong:)

Comment: @MissMulan yeah probably, when the transistor is active it measures 500kA through the collector.

Comment: Post a cropped screengrab of your simulator setup. What value have you got for the supply voltage and RL?

Comment: @Transistor I'll edit the question. 5V and 100kOhm

Comment: Your simulation schematic looks OK as far as I can see. With 100k in there on a 5 V circuit the current should be 50 µA. The simulator isn't using a capital 'M' (mega) instead of 'm' for 'milli' or 'µ' for 'micro', is it?

Comment: @Transistor no it's not. I didn't accept your answer because I guess you assumed I was talking about an open Vout and not something like the circuit I uploaded later.

Comment: Check what the recommended pull-up resistor value is for 74LS series. 100k might be too high (but it doesn't explain the high current problem).